# Not able to SignOut using flutter And Firebase But I can Sign in

Tags: flutter

I am not being able to sign out of the Project. Someone please help.
I just have following error going on.

Debug Console Says :

```
Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth(10573): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
E/flutter (10573): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(status, Failed to disconnect., null, null)
E/flutter (10573): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
E/flutter (10573): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:158
E/flutter (10573): <asynchronous suspension>

D/FirebaseAuth(12606): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth(12606): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
E/flutter (12606): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(status, Failed to disconnect., null, null)
```

My Code looks like this::

```
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final userReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.now();
MyUser? currentUser;


  Future loginUser() async {
    googleSignIn.signIn();
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((googleSignIn) {
      controlSignIn(googleSignIn!);
    }, onError: (e) {
      print("Error Message" + e);
    });
  }

  Future logoutUser() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut().then((value) {}).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
  }
```